# React add OneSignal to existing ServiceWorker

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, onesignal

I am facing probably a quite trivial problem right now. I have an existing React Application with a ServiceWorker that handles caching and other stuff.

Now I want to add OneSignal Push Notifications to my Application. But every tutorial I find is quite outdated or not working (for me).

##### The Steps I have done for now:

- I have created my OneSignal Account and created a Web Configuration with the following setup:
  [image: Web Configuration for OneSignal]
- I have downloaded the OneSignalServiceWorker.js file and placed it into the `public` folder of my React App
- I added the folowing line to the file: `importScripts("\service-worker.js")` to add my own ServiceWorker

The Error I get:

[image]

##### Result

Ideally I need a step by step guide on what to do, so I can recieve Push-Notifications in the Foreground and Background of my React PWA.